# Form $dirty is false on typeahead select

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

`$dirty` is false even after selecting the value from dropdown. Is there an alternative to setting the dirty flag?

[JSBin here](https://jsbin.com/bitifeg/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the input value as `$dirty` yourself in combination with an `ng-change` function ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)). *EDIT*: I found that with ui-bootstrap it's better to use `typeahead-on-select` since it doesn't work well with `ng-change`.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var _selected;

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];

  $scope.x = {
    User: {
      username: ''
    }
  };
})
```

```css
.typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper>.message {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #868686;
}

.typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper>.dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  min-width: 160px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
    <a>
      <img ng-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/{{match.model.flag}}" width="16">
      <span ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
    </a>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="customPopupTemplate.html">
    <div class="custom-popup-wrapper" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" style="display: block;" ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
      <p class="message">select location from drop down.</p>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
        <li class="uib-typeahead-match" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
          <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </script>

  <div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <form name="testForm">
      <h4>Static arrays</h4>
      <pre>Model: {{selected | json}} </pre>
      <input type="text" ng-model="x.User.username" typeahead-on-select='testForm.$setDirty();' uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" typeahead-min-length="0">
      <input ng-model="x.User.username" required/>
    </form>
    {{testForm.$dirty}}
  </div>
</body>
```

You can also move the logic inside the controller of course. I hope this helps.

Comment: It is better to use the [$setDirty()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setDirty) method. It will update the classes and inform the [ngFormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg! I updated the answer to reflect that